# _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL inconsistency

Tags: visual-c++

We are trying to embed a debug version of [V8 library](https://v8.dev/docs/embed) statically. The problem arises that the macro `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` which is set to `2` by default (and something that we prefer in debug mode) forces us to build V8 too with this setting but this leads to huge performance penalties drastically impacting the runtime performance (NOTE: performance isn't a concern on debug builds but this almost makes it unusable). Is there a way, in general (since this doesn't seem V8-specific), to link to libraries with different `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`? I think that it might be problematic because the linker anyway complains of a mismatch and theoretically too it seems to be dangerous because this alters the representation of STL data structures and thus leads to an ABI mismatch. What's the best way to deal with such issues while ensuring ABI compatibility but still having recourse to iterator debugging? Having gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771935/c-linking-release-built-library-with-my-debug-build), it seems that it's something that the library (V8 in this case) needs to do.

Comment: No, you really can't mix.  Iterator debugging changes the size of std template objects, having them mixed causes horrible memory corruption problems.  If perf is important while debugging then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Perf isn't a concern on debug builds for us too but it almost becomes unusable for some workflows, which is why I thought if we could somehow tide over it.