# loading BMP __imp___CrtDbgReportW error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I was attempting to load an image and I received this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW
referenced in function "public: char const & __thiscall
std::_String_const_iterator<class 
std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > >::operator*(void)const " 
(??D?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@QBEABDXZ)   
C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\
ConsoleApplication4\Terrain.obj
```

I've checked the MSDN forum and tried solve the problem by removing `_DEBUG` from the preprocessor/ add `/MTd` to the command line, but neither proposed solutions worked.

I've narrowed the problem down to the ImageLoader class, but have no idea on how to resolve the issue... I've been following [THIS](http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/terrain/home.php) tutorial, which supplies the Image loading class.

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this error?

Comment: You are mixing code compiled with different compile options.  To resolve this link error you will at least need /MDd, /MTd cannot work.  Best thing to do is to carefully review all projects that you link, possibly having to recompile a .lib that you got elsewhere.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the input. /MDd solved the error, but now I have Unhandled exception at 0x1000BB1E (glut32.dll) in ConsoleApplication4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000070.

Comment: @SpicyWeenie If you're linking in other dependencies then one of the other dependencies may still have been compiled with /MD.  So at runtime, the entry point for a C-runtime function may be incorrect.  All dependencies have to be compiled to link to the same type of C-runtime library.  Otherwise you're likely to encounter Access violations or other such errors.  This might give more information... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746298/how-do-you-build-a-debug-exe-msvcrtd-lib-against-a-release-built-lib-msvcrt